# How to keep Main window active while iFrame is focused

Tags: javascript, session, iframe, focus

In the main window we have an application (that has inactivity time-out in seconds), Main application launches another application inside iFrame. While user is working in the application inside iFrame, Main application window becomes inactive (because focus is on iFrame) and logs-out.

To prevent this from happening, we need to check if there's a way to manage the session active using javascript.

FYI, we have used Post-message (*) to close iFrame and navigate back on main Window (this shouldn't be disrupted either).
I thought of using `document.getElementById("<MainWindow>").focus();` with a time-out and loop this way (**) in the Main Window's javascript. I'm yet to test if this works, but is there a better way to achieve the requirement?

(*)
**iFrame window**

```
postMessage("foo", targetOrigin)
```

**Main window**

```
window.addEventListener(   "message",   (event) => {
    if (Message == "foo") //navigate to next page

    // … 


},   false );
```

(**)

```
function OnNavigationtoiFrame()
{
    var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 10000);
}

function myTimer() {
     document.getElementById("<MainWindow>").focus() = true;
}
```

FYI, the main application is Siebel. And it has session time-out.

Comment: what are the conditions for a timeout to occur? maybe it is not related to window focus state, but rather time since last operation? [source](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88140_01/books/Secur/secur_configparams006.htm#:~:text=The%20Active%20Session%20Timeout%20Value%20parameter%20is%20the%20time%2C%20in,guidelines%20for%20setting%20this%20parameter.&text=Greater%20than%2030%20minutes.&text=Greater%20than%2030%20minutes.,-Less%20than%205)

Comment: Timeout of focus you can consider